# Does activity archival decrease the storage limit?

Tags: activities, archive

Salesforce [archives Activities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=activities_archived.htm&type=5) after a year of due date end.

What I didn't find is - does archival decrease the Storage Limit consumption?
I.e., there're 1kk tasks in the org and the storage consumed by them is 2 GB. A week later those tasks are archived. Will the storage consumption still be 2 GB? Or it will be 0, since those 1kk tasks were archived?

Please point me to SFDC documentation if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting archived activities decreases consumed storage. Hence archived records still consume storage.